# May we axiomatize by means of Gödel codes?

Tags: lo.logic

Suppose we have a classical arithmetical theory $\mathbf{R}$, at least as strong as Robinson arithmetic, with $\tau$ an extra dummy monadic predicate in its language $\mathcal{L}$. Suppose $\mathbf{R}$ only has modus ponens as an inference rule.

Let the variables of $\mathcal{L}$ be indexed by the natural numbers. For a formula $\epsilon$ in $\mathcal{L}$, let $\forall\epsilon$ be $\epsilon$ if there are no free variables in $\epsilon$, else $\forall\forall x_i\epsilon$ where $x_i$ is the free variable of $\epsilon$ with smallest index.

Let the axiomatization of $\mathbf{R}$ be such that all the axioms are of the form $\forall\zeta$ for some $\zeta$ in $\mathcal{L}$, so that $\mathbf{R}$ only has sentences as axioms.

Suppose $\mathbf{R}$ has, for example, the axioms $A^1 \ \forall\alpha$, $A^2 \ \forall\beta$ and $A^3 \ \forall\gamma$, and, to repeat, just modus ponens as inference rule.

Suppose [] is a Gödel-coding provided by $\mathbf{R}$.

May I define a system  such as $\mathbf{T}$, in the following,  by using axioms $A^{\tau1} \ \tau[\forall\alpha]$, $A^{\tau 2} \ \tau[\forall\beta]$, $A^{\tau 3} \ \tau[\forall\gamma]$, as well as $A^{\tau 4} \ \tau[\tau[\forall\forall x_i\eta(x_i)]\leftrightarrow\forall\forall x_i\tau[\eta(\dot{x_i})]]$ and $A^{\tau 5} \ \tau[\forall\delta]\to\forall\delta,$ and the inference rule $\vdash\tau[\forall\epsilon] \ \& \ \vdash\tau[\forall\epsilon\to\forall\zeta] \ \Rightarrow \ \vdash\tau[\forall\zeta]$? If not, why not?

Comment: Maybe this is standard notation but what are these double $\forall$s, and what is $\eta(\dot{x_i}]$?

Comment: Can you be a bit more explicit about "only modus ponens as inference rule". Your logic has the universal quantifier, how are you ever going to prove anything involving $\forall$, or use it, if there are no rules for $\forall$? In a similar fashion: modus ponens lets you eliminate an implication, but how do you intend to prove an implication (you don't have any rules for that). Are we talking natural deduction or Hilbert system here?

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე The double $\forall$s are defined in paragraph 2. In $\forall x_i\tau[\eta(\dot{x_i})]$, $\eta$ is a formula, and $\eta(\dot{x_i})$ is the formula resulting from substituting the occurrences of $x_i$ in $\eta$ with the numeral $\dot{x_i}$ denoting $[x_i]$. So $\eta(\dot{x_i})$ is $\eta(\dot{x_i}/[x_i])$.

Comment: @AndrejBauer One may avoid generalization as a primitive inference rule if one axiom states that $\forall x\delta$ is an axiom if $\delta$ is an axiom, and one has $\forall x(\delta\to\epsilon)\to(\forall x\delta\to\forall x\epsilon)$ (Tarski? Cfr. e.g. G. Hunter, Metalogic, Part Three.)

Comment: @AndrejBauer Lonely universal quantifiers are metalogical devices, bound by paragraph 2 of the question. So, e.g., $\forall(x_1 =x_0\to(x_0 =x_1\to x_0=x_1))$ is $\forall x_1\forall x_0(x_1 =x_0\to(x_0 =x_1\to x_1=x_0))$.

Comment: @AndrejBauer As seen by my previous paragraph, lonely universal quantifiers secure universal generalisations of the axioms. I have in mind Hilbert style systems here.

Comment: As we may see, $\mathbf{R}$ should have the axiom $\vdash\forall(\delta\to\epsilon)\to(\forall\delta\to\forall\epsilon)$.

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე Correction: $[\eta(\dot{x_i})]$ is short for $[\eta](\dot{x_i}/[x_i])$, where $\dot{~}$ is the function which takes a number to its numeral.

Comment: I see, thanks. Though I still don't understand the meaning of the double $\forall$, also in the second paragraph.

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე For example, $\forall\forall x_3\exists y(y>x_3\cdot x_4\cdot x_2)$ is $\forall x_4\forall x_2\forall x_3\exists y(y>x_3\cdot x_4\cdot x_2)$.

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე: replace all outer $\forall$ with something like $\mathrm{UniversalClosure}$. The OP is just defining what it means to have a universal closure of a formula, i.e., $\mathrm{UniversalClosure}(\epsilon) = \epsilon$ if $\epsilon$ is closed, and $\mathrm{UniversalClosure}(\epsilon) = \mathrm{UniversalClosure}(\forall x_i \, \epsilon)$ if the first free variable in $\epsilon$ is $\epsilon_i$. The OP however likes to save on parentheses and writes $\mathrm{UniversalClosure}$ as $\forall$, to make things more intuitive.

Comment: Oh now I understand, thank you